# Use Pyxl to read Excel spreadsheet data up to a certain row

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I created an Excel spreadsheet using Pandas and xlsxwriter, which has all the data in the right rows and columns. However, the formatting in xlsxwriter is pretty basic, so I want to solve this problem by writing my Pandas spreadsheet on top of a template spreadsheet with Pyxl.

First, however, I need to get Pyxl to only import data up to the first blank row, and to get rid of the column headings. This way I could write my Excel data from the xlsxwriter output to the template.

I have no clue how to go about this and can't find it here or in the docs. Any ideas?

How about if I want to read data from the first column after the first blank column? (I can think of a workaround for this, but it would help if I knew how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I'd be tempted to suggest you use openpyxl all the way if there is something that xlsxwriter doesn't do, though I think that it's formatting options are pretty extensive. The most recent version of openpyxl is as fast as xlsxwriter if lxml is installed.

However, it's worth noting that Pandas has tended to ship with an older version of openpyxl because we changed the style API.

Otherwise you can use `max_row` to get the highest row but this won't check for an empty row.

Comment: Well neither seem ideal. xlsxwriter is great but doesn't seem to format column headers from a pandas dataframe. The workaround I want to do is to get a template and just copy the column headers, pasting them into the spreadsheet produced by xlsxwriter. I tried closing the original xlsxwriter output and opening the saved spreadsheet again so I could work on it outside of the context of pandas with xlsxwriter again, but xlsxwriter doesn't read data?

Comment: I don't know enough about how Pandas works but openpyxl would allow you to work with a template and just add the data.

We hope to improve the support for Pandas in a future release so that you can work with Dataframes within openpyxl.

Comment: XlsxWriter supports all of Excel's cell, row, and column formatting. However, formatting via Pandas is limited (by Pandas) to some default styles common to all Excel writers. See the following for some information about [Working with Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html). If that doesn't do what you need then just create a new XlsxWriter file, outside the Pandas interface, copy in the data from the dataframe, and apply any formatting that you want.

Comment: But then I still can't alter the column headings - it seems that the pandas formatting overrides xlsxwriter's?

Comment: Ah ok - I can do header = False and just write to the first column with xlsxwriter - if it works 2mo I will mark this as fixed